# How do I change the representation of a Python function?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

```
>>> def hehe():
...     return "spam"
... 
>>> repr(hehe)
'<function hehe at 0x7fe5624e29b0>'
```

I want to have:

```
>>> repr(hehe)
'hehe function created by awesome programmer'
```

How do I do that? Putting `__repr__` inside `hehe` function does not work.

**EDIT:**

In case you guys are wondering why I want to do this:

```
>>> defaultdict(hehe)
defaultdict(<function hehe at 0x7f0e0e252280>, {})
```

I just don't like the way it shows here.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I answered your question in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually, when you want to change something about the function, say function signature, function behavior or function attributes, you should consider using a decorator. So here is how you might implement what you want:

```
class change_repr(object):
    def __init__(self, functor):
        self.functor = functor

        #  lets copy some key attributes from the original function
        self.__name__ = functor.__name__
        self.__doc__ = functor.__doc__

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.functor(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<function %s created by ...>' % self.functor.__name__


@change_repr
def f():
    return 'spam'


print f()  # spam
print repr(f)  # <function hehe created by ...>
```

Note, that you can only use class based decorator, since you need to override `__repr__` method, which you can't do with a function object.

Comment: "decorator" seems like a bad name (i.e., too generic!) for your decorator.

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot change the representation of a function object; if you wanted to add *documentation*, you'd add a docstring:

```
def foo():
    """Frob the bar baz"""
```

and access that with `help(foo)` or `print foo.__doc__`.

You *can* create a callable object with a custom `__repr__`, which acts just like a function:

```
class MyCallable(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return "spam"
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'hehe function created by awesome programmer'
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MyCallable(object):
...     def __call__(self):
...         return "spam"
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'hehe function created by awesome programmer'
... 
>>> hehe = MyCallable()
>>> hehe
hehe function created by awesome programmer
>>> hehe()
'spam'
```

Comment: function objects can not be subclassed. So one needs to create an own class like you did.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly the answer to your question, but perhaps you really want a docstring?

```
>>> def hehe():
...  '''hehe function created by awesome programmer'''
...  return 'spam'
...
>>> help(hehe)
Help on function hehe in module __main__:

hehe()
    hehe function created by awesome programmer
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more flexible version of what's in Alexander Zhukov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20094262/355230):

```
def representation(repr_text):
    class Decorator(object):
        def __init__(self, functor):
            self.functor = functor

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.functor(*args, **kwargs)

        def __repr__(self):
            return (repr_text % self.functor.__name__ if '%' in repr_text
                    else repr_text)

    return Decorator

from collections import defaultdict

@representation('<function %s created by awesome programmer>')
def f():
    return list

dd = defaultdict(f)
print repr(dd)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function f created by awesome programmer>, {})
```

Since`representation()`returns a decorator, if you wanted the same boilerplate on several functions you could do something like this:

```
myrepr = representation('<function %s created by awesome programmer>')

@myrepr
def f():
    ...

@myrepr
def g():
    ...

etc
```