# Convert list of file paths to a nested dictionary similar to a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried several solutions that I found on stack overflow but I either end up with empty dictionaries at the end of the branch or a filemarker when moving from dictionary to list of files.

The problem:
A python list object

```
paths =[/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove
/etc/bluetooth/serial.conf.dpkg-remove
/etc/bluetooth/input.conf
/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf.dpkg-remove
/etc/bluetooth/network.conf
/etc/bluetooth/main.conf
/etc/fish
/etc/fish/completions
/etc/fish/completions/task.fish]

expected output:
{"etc" : 
    {"bluetooth" : 
        ["rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove",
         "serial.conf.dpkg-remove",
         "input.conf",
         "audio.conf.dpkg-remove",
         "network.conf",
         "main.conf"],
     "fish" : 
        {"completions" : "task.fish"}}}
```

I found that I was able to output this in javascript using: [Parse string of file path to json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704201/parse-string-of-file-path-to-json-object)

Is there a way to use dafaultdict to create lists of leafs without any preceding text?

This got me closest to what I am looking for but I am left with file marker(defaultdict(dict, ((FILE_MARKER, []),))) at each node.

```
from collections import defaultdict


FILE_MARKER = '<files>'

def attach(branch, trunk):
    '''
    Insert a branch of directories on its trunk.
    '''
    parts = branch.split('/', 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:  # branch is a file
        trunk[FILE_MARKER].append(parts[0])
    else:
        node, others = parts
        if node not in trunk:
            trunk[node] = defaultdict(dict, ((FILE_MARKER, []),))
        attach(others, trunk[node])
```

Comment: have you done any research on this or attempted to solve this in any way?

Comment: yes, posted my code above. Tried several things in python and have a descent looking json but cant get rid of the defaultdict text in the dictionary

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _" but I am left with file marker(defaultdict(dict, ((FILE_MARKER, []),))) at each node."_

Comment: Also, what would you do if a directory contains child directories _and_ files? For example if you had `/etc/bluetooth/subdirectory/some.file.1` as one of your `paths`?

Comment: Your output is different for children in bluetooth, which is a list, compared to the children in completions, which is a string. What is your prefered solution there? Also what should happen when you have your paths, but also something like this `/etc/bluetooth/part1/something`, then you have an ending and an extra depth? Will the final end then be a dictionary and a list, or does that not happen in your code at all? (edit: see @pranav Hosangadi his comment is more clear)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - if you look at my code, I created an object to mark my files in the list directory. and for the second question, this needs to be recursive as we do not know the depths of all filepaths. Darryl's solution has answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
from pprint import pprint as pp # For pretty printing nested dictioanry

def make_path(paths):
    # Sort so deepest paths are first
    paths = sorted(paths, key = lambda s: len(s.lstrip('/').split('/')), reverse = True)

    tree_path = {}
    for path in paths:
        # Split into list and remove leading '/' if present
        levels = path.lstrip('/').split("/")
        
        file = levels.pop()
        acc = tree_path
        for i, p in enumerate(levels, start = 1):
            if i == len(levels):
                # Reached termination of a path
                # Use current terminal object is present, else use list
                acc[p] = acc[p] if p in acc else []
                if isinstance(acc[p], list):
                    # Only append if we are at a list
                    acc[p].append(file)
            else:
                # Exaand with dictionary by default
                acc.setdefault(p, {})
            acc = acc[p]

    return tree_path
```

**Usage**

*Example 1*

```
paths =['/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove',
        '/etc/bluetooth/serial.conf.dpkg-remove',
        '/etc/bluetooth/input.conf',
        '/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf.dpkg-remove',
        '/etc/bluetooth/network.conf',
        '/etc/bluetooth/main.conf',
        '/etc/fish',
        '/etc/fish/completions',
        '/etc/fish/completions/task.fish']

res = make_path(paths)
pp(res)  # Pretty print result
```

*Output*

```
{'etc': {'bluetooth': ['rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove',
                       'serial.conf.dpkg-remove',
                       'input.conf',
                       'audio.conf.dpkg-remove',
                       'network.conf',
                       'main.conf'],
         'fish': {'completions': ['task.fish']}}}
```

*Example 2*

```
paths = [
  "path1/subpath1/file111.doc",
  "path1/subpath1/file112.doc",
  "path1/subpath2/file121.doc",
  "path1/subpath2/file122.doc",
  "path2/subpath1/file211.doc",
  "path2/subpath1/file212.doc",
  "path2/subpath2/file221.doc",
  "path2/subpath2/file222.doc",
  "path2/additionalpath3/additionalpath1/file2311.doc"
]
res = make_path(paths)
pp(res)  # Pretty print result
```

*Output*

```
{'path1': {'subpath1': ['file111.doc', 'file112.doc'],
           'subpath2': ['file121.doc', 'file122.doc']},
 'path2': {'additionalpath3': {'additionalpath1': ['file2311.doc']},
           'subpath1': ['file211.doc', 'file212.doc'],
           'subpath2': ['file221.doc', 'file222.doc']}}
```

Comment: Thanks Darryl, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: I did upvote but it is not shown publicly as I have less than 15 reputations. Hopefully, it will show up once I meet the pre-requisite

Comment: @KautilyaNalubolu--the other option is to accept as the answer which does not have a prerequisite I believe.

Comment: Accepted it as the answer @DarrylG

Answer (score 2):

The problem is closely related to a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).
When taking the following input

```
paths = [
    "/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove",
    "/etc/bluetooth/serial.conf.dpkg-remove",
    "/etc/bluetooth/input.conf",
    "/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf.dpkg-remove",
    "/etc/bluetooth/network.conf",
    "/etc/bluetooth/main.conf",
    "/etc/bluetooth/subdirectory/main.conf",
    "/etc/fish",
    "/etc/fish/completions",
    "/etc/fish/completions/task.fish"
]
```

We can quickly construct a Trie using the following

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from pprint import pprint

# ... your input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = lambda: defaultdict(node)
    parts = node()
    
    for path in paths:
        reduce(dict.__getitem__, path[1:].split('/'), parts)
    pprint(parts, width=10)
```

Which results in the following Trie

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>,
            {'etc': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>,
                                {'bluetooth': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>,
                                                          {'audio.conf.dpkg-remove': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {}),
                                                           'input.conf': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {}),
                                                           'main.conf': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {}),
                                                           'network.conf': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {}),
                                                           'rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {}),
                                                           'serial.conf.dpkg-remove': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {}),
                                                           'subdirectory': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>,
                                                                                       {'main.conf': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {})})}),
                                 'fish': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>,
                                                     {'completions': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>,
                                                                                 {'task.fish': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001E34CC06E50>, {})})})})})
```

#### Clean up

Now you might want to make it slightly prettier, by removing the `defaultdict` aspect of the Trie, by either following

- [How do I change the representation of a Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093811/how-do-i-change-the-representation-of-a-python-function)

or making a normal dictionary out of it, with an ending token, see

- Clean up code

  ```
  def simplify(dictionary):
      if isinstance(dictionary, defaultdict):
          return {k: simplify(v) or None for k, v in dictionary.items()}
      return dictionary
  ```
- Usage

  ```
  pprint(simplify(parts))
  ```
- Output

  ```
  {'etc': {'bluetooth': {'audio.conf.dpkg-remove': None,
                         'input.conf': None,
                         'main.conf': None,
                         'network.conf': None,
                         'rfcomm.conf.dpkg-remove': None,
                         'serial.conf.dpkg-remove': None,
                         'subdirectory': {'main.conf': None}},
           'fish': {'completions': {'task.fish': None}}}}
  ```

#### Limitations

I do assume here that it is oké, to indicate a file by giving it the value `None`. This way it can properly handle subdirectories and all endings are clearly indicated.

Another (implicit) assumption is that the Trie only has to be constructed a single time when simplifying. If you want to keep adding extra paths to it afterwards, I would advice to keep the `defaultdict` version of the Trie.

Comment: Thank you Thymen, but Darryl's reply is more apt for what I was trying to accomplish